# error in google login fragment, W/IInputConnectionWrapper(20367): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, google-signin

I have this error when i click the google login button:
W/IInputConnectionWrapper(20367): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
 but i don't know how i have this problem, I read that this error is due to a connection not closed earlier but do not understand what. Please someone help me

```
  `*package com.amuse.facebooktutorial;
    public class GoogleLoginFragment extends Fragment implements OnClickListener,
    ConnectionCallbacks, OnConnectionFailedListener {
    private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 0;
    private static final int RESULT_OK = 0;
    // Logcat tag
    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
    // Google client to interact with Google API
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private static final int REQ_SIGN_IN_REQUIRED = 55664;
    /**
    * A flag indicating that a PendingIntent is in progress and prevents us
    * from starting further intents.
    */
    private boolean mIntentInProgress;
    private boolean mSignInClicked;
    private ConnectionResult mConnectionResult;
    private SignInButton btnSignIn;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }
    @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.google_login_layout, container, false);

            btnSignIn = (SignInButton) view.findViewById(R.id.google_login_button);


            mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getActivity())
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this).addApi(Plus.API)
            .addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN).build(); 


            btnSignIn.setOnClickListener(this);
            try {
                if (Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient) != null) {
                    Person currentPerson = Plus.PeopleApi
                            .getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient);

                    String email = Plus.AccountApi.getAccountName(mGoogleApiClient);
                    String id = currentPerson.getId()+"$GOOGLE";
                    String token = new RetrieveTokenTask().execute(email).toString();



                    ((MainActivity)getActivity()).googleLogin(id, token);
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                            "Person information is null", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

       return view;


        }
    public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }
    public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    }
    }
    /**
    * Method to resolve any signin errors
    * */
    private void resolveSignInError() {
    if (mConnectionResult.hasResolution()) {
        try {
            mIntentInProgress = true;
            mConnectionResult.startResolutionForResult(getActivity(), RC_SIGN_IN);
        } catch (SendIntentException e) {
            mIntentInProgress = false;
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        }
    }
    }
    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
    if (!result.hasResolution()) {
        GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(result.getErrorCode(), getActivity(),
                0).show();
        return;
    }
    if (!mIntentInProgress) {
        // Store the ConnectionResult for later usage
        mConnectionResult = result;
        if (mSignInClicked) {
            // The user has already clicked 'sign-in' so we attempt to
            // resolve all
            // errors until the user is signed in, or they cancel.
            resolveSignInError();
        }
    }
    }
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int responseCode,
        Intent intent) {
    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        if (responseCode != RESULT_OK) {
            mSignInClicked = false;
        }
        mIntentInProgress = false;
        if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnecting()) {
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        }
    }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle Bundle) {
    mSignInClicked = false;
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "User is connected!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int arg0) {
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }
    /**
    * Button on click listener
    * */
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.google_login_button:
        // Signin button clicked
        signInWithGplus();
        break;
    }
    }
    /**
    * Sign-in into google
    * */
    private void signInWithGplus() {
    if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnecting()) {
        mSignInClicked = true;
        resolveSignInError();
    }
    }
    private class RetrieveTokenTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String accountName = params[0];
        String scopes = "oauth2:profile email";
        String token = null;
        try {
            token = GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), accountName, scopes);
            Log.e("token", token);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
        } catch (UserRecoverableAuthException e) {
            startActivityForResult(e.getIntent(), REQ_SIGN_IN_REQUIRED);
        } catch (GoogleAuthException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
        }
        return token;
    }
    }
    }*
    `
```

Answer (score 0):

First
You need to check your AndroidManifest.xml file.
Check the activity that owns GoogleLoginFragment has been set noHistory="true" attribute.

Second
You need to check your server connection is closed on previous class or Activity.

I hope this would help.